# How loose are the terms "independent" and "dependent" variables?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, terminology

If I am going to buy $c$ number of cats and they each cost \$100, and the total is $t$

My equation would look like:

$100c = t$

Here, my dependent variable is $t$ and my independent variable is $c$

Or so I thought, I can rearrange this to get:

$t/100 = c$

In this case is $t$ the dependent? If I have the price $t$ and the output is how many cats I will buy $c$. Although, this is strange, hypothetically some old cat lady could have saved up a certain amount of money and just wants to buy as many cats as possible.

So, if this is the case, what should someone answer in a test? If they are loose like how I have just proved, then how could a student differentiate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be counter intuitive, but while dependent and independent variables are perfectly well-defined concepts, they are not mathematical concepts - they are part of the formulation of the experimental method in science.

When one performs an experiment, one typically controls some parameter (say $x$) in the experiment, and measures an outcome (say $y$) as a result. At this point, $x$ and $y$ are discrete variables, summarizing the results of the experiment: when I held $x$ to a certain value, I measured $y$ as another value, and so on. Mathematically, we have an empirically measured function $f\colon \{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}\to \{y_1,\ldots,y_n\}$ where the $x_i$ are the finite set of values I set the parameter to, and the $y_i$ are the finite set of results I measured.

Now we typically try to fit the results of an experiment to a mathematical model, in which case we are approximating the measured function $f$ above by an abstract mathematical function, usually defined for infinitely many values. As you pointed out, once we pass to the mathematical abstraction, the roles of $x$ and $y$ can be interchanged.

**In summary,** the concept of dependent and independent variables refer to the setup of an experiment or measurement, and are not directly reflected in the mathematical model of the functional relationship.

Comment: Alright thanks for the great answer! So on a test one should pay attention to the wording of the situation?

Comment: Yes, I would pay keen attention to the setup of the problem and ignore the actual math if I was asked to distinguish a dependent variable from an independent variable.

Answer (score 2):

In situations like this, context is usually key.

As a rule of thumb; if I see $y=mx+c$ ie one variable on one side and many variables on the other. The solo variable is usually the dependent variable. In the above equation $y$ is dependent on $x$.

Regarding this particular example, we could ask ourselves:

- if I buy many cats will the total price I need to pay change? Yes, since the total price is a function of the number of cats multiplied by 100.
- Given that I buy many cats, will the price for a given cat change? Hmm, not really. Unless there is some sort of discount offer, you buying many cats will not affect the price of a single cat.

Comment: But C is the number of cats, you stated that the price would be changing when I have the number of cats $c$ changing, did you make a mistake or have I? Could you please fix it or inform me of how to fix my question? Anyway, thanks for answering! :)

Comment: My mistake, by price I meant the total price, not the price for a single cat. So the total price would change the more cats you buy. But the price of a single cat would stay the same, even if you bought 100 cats.

Comment: So is your answer wrong? Look at +pre-kidney*s answer

Comment: The answer still seems to hold. With regards to the above answer, it also seems to be correct; we seem to be saying the same thing. Ie it’s about the context. You can ask the two questions I asked in my answer to get a better feel for what the independent and dependent variables. Note: that in a physics experiment, we usually have things that we try to control so that only a few things are dependent on others in an experiment. Looking at it purely from a mathematical point of view, I would use the number of variables to try and figure it out.